# How to adjust ul width property?

Tags: html, css

```
<ul id='ul01'>
    <li><a href='#'><img src='img01.png' width="700" height="590" /></a></li>
    <li><a href='#'><img src='img02.png' width="700" height="590" /></a></li>
    <li><a href='#'><img src='img03.png' width="700" height="590" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#ul01{list-style:none;width:??;}
#ul01 li{float:left;}
```

This is a horizontal array of images. list.items.count can vary.
What should be the width property to fit all images.
I tried with - auto - and expected resizible width - but it's not.

Comment: each image (700px) already fills the width of the screen?

Comment: Can you clearly describe what you're looking for here?

Comment: I want to adjust ul width to fit all images. Number of images varies. List should stay horizontal, not vertical.

Comment: So the page width can grow (to infinity?) and you're fine with horizontal scrolling?

Comment: But I can't write width: infinity.

Comment: Check [magicalex's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11520529/1047823) answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make the `li` elements `inline-block`s and set the `white-space` property of the `ul` to `nowrap`.

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
}
ul {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make these change i think these will work for you...

```html
#ul01{list-style:none;width:100%;}
#ul01 li{float:left; width:33%; }
#ul01 li a { display:block; }
#ul01 li a img { width:100%; height:auto; }

<ul id='ul01'>
    <li><a href='#'><img src='img01.png' /></a></li>
    <li><a href='#'><img src='img02.png' /></a></li>
    <li><a href='#'><img src='img03.png' /></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: but the OP has a fixed image height and width

Comment: that didnt matter but the benefit is image with any size will adjust for that

Comment: You can't offer a pig while the OP wants a cow and say "it doesn't matter you can eat both"

Answer (score 1):

if your images have to retain the sizes you specified then know that your page will have horizontal scrollbar. If you prefer that this will work

```
#ul01{list-style:none;width:2100px;}
#ul01 li{float:left; width:700px}
```

The `ul` width has to be the `(width X 3) + (2 X image-border-if-any} + padding` = `2100px + n`

Answer (score 0):

try jquery, so in css file you can put 0, and value would be change later.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $('#ul01 li img').each(function() {
      sum += parseInt($(this).attr("width"), 10);
    });
    $('#ul01').css({ 'width': sum+'px' });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just put width property to ul element.