# Need to have images listed horizontally instead of vertical

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a very simple jquery slider, instead of using one of the millions probably out there. So I have almost finished it, but I have a problem. I'm using jquery's animate to move the images, and I need to show all images on the same horizontal line to get the script working. Now, they're listed vertically, and I've been thinking this for 2 hours now. So here's the HTML:

```
<div id="gallery-wrap">
<div id="gallery">
    <img class="galleryimage" src="http://materiaalit.kotisivut.name/sivustokuvat/ccc.PNG" alt="" />
    <img class="galleryimage"  src="http://materiaalit.kotisivut.name/sivustokuvat/coverline.PNG" alt="" />
    <img class="galleryimage"  src="http://materiaalit.kotisivut.name/sivustokuvat/ccc.PNG" alt="" />
    <img class="galleryimage"  src="http://materiaalit.kotisivut.name/sivustokuvat/coverline.PNG" alt="" />
    <img class="galleryimage"  src="http://materiaalit.kotisivut.name/sivustokuvat/ccc.PNG" alt="" />
    <img class="galleryimage"  src="http://materiaalit.kotisivut.name/sivustokuvat/coverline.PNG" alt="" />
</div>
<div id="gallery-controls">
<a id="gallery-prev" href="#"><img alt="" /> </a>
<a id="gallery-next" href="#"><img alt="" /></a></div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

The CSS:

```css
    #gallery-wrap{margin: 0 auto; overflow: visible; width: 100%; position: relative; height:300px; border:1px solid black; border-radius:6px; z-index:3;}
#gallery{position: relative; left: 0; top: 0; width:100%;}
.galleryimage{float:left; width:100%; height:300px;}

#gallery-controls{width: 100%; z-index:4;}
#gallery-prev{position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width:50%; height:300px; background-color:rgba(77,77,77,0.5);}
#gallery-next{position:absolute; right:0px; top:0px;  width:50%; height:300px; background-color:rgba(88,88,88,0.5);}
```

And the jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 

    $("#gallery-prev").click(function(){
  $(".galleryimage").animate({"left": "-=100%"}, "slow");
});

$("#gallery-next").click(function(){
  $(".galleryimage").animate({"left": "+=100%"}, "slow");
});

});
```

Here's a picture to show how the images are rendered at the moment just in case I explained something wrong, English isn't my first language:

[image]

I've tried display:inline without luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `#gallery li img {display:inline;}`

Instead apply `display:inline;`  to this `#gallery li` and remove it from `#gallery li img`

```css
#gallery li{width: /*here goes some width*/; height: 300px; float:left; display: inline;}
```

And don't use width of your image and li element as 100%, check this out [My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hdUZb/2/)

I saw the source of your page, assuming that you need all the images in a single horizontal row, set a width to your `<li>` element, and use `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` before the text paragraphs to clear out the floats.

Comment: No help, did that, removed the float:left; part, but still looking same.

Comment: Here's what your fiddle does.

Comment: adjust the widths and if you want text below your images use a clear fix <div style="clear: both;"></div> after your gallery <div> to clear it because you are using floats

Comment: The text is the content that should appear below the slider... I want that the images are on the same horizontal line, and when they do, I set the overflow of the gallery to hidden, and the images will slide if you click the controls.

Comment: I gave it 800px width, but it didn't do anything special. I also used the <div style="clear:both"></div>

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen you can't have 800px width for each of your li elements, try width of 100px or 80px

Comment: The images I will use are about 800px. You probably misunderstood me. I want to show one image at a time, and that's why I want them on single horizontal line, and that's why I will use overflow:hidden;

Comment: Yeah, a slideshow. Like I thought I said in the first place. I corrected the code to match the current one.

Answer (score 0):

Use `float:left` instead of `display:inline` to force the inline flow without losing sizing capabilities.

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/hdUZb/):

If you want to force it to not wrap with narrow browser window, set a fixed width to the gallery like so:

```css
#gallery
{
    width: 1500px;
}
```

Comment: I did that, but it didn't do anything.

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen. Check out the example in my answer. It works.

Comment: And the page has a fixed width, so if I use percents, it's the percent value of the page fixed width

Answer (score 0):

You can let the container of the image have

```
{
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

as answered on this question [How to adjust ul width property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520214/how-to-adjust-ul-width-property/11520544#11520544)